ubuntu pnetlab issue
I am trying to install ubuntu desktop 24.04 as a QEMU image to run it in PNETLab, I did the conversion to qcow2 from iso successfully, and the image boots up to the installation, however it complains that there's not enough space despite PNET's vdisk is at 100G. how to solve this ?

Are you sure this newest version of Ubuntu will even run in the way you are trying? With PNETLab.

update: it boots up finally and let me choose disks and pursue the installation, but it says 'unknown error' after that
